# Membase benchmarks and usage

Tags: nosql, membase

Does anyone know if there are some published benchmark results for Membase? The project looks interesting, but it seems that there hasn't been a lot written about it.
Apart from Zynga and Northscale, are there any users out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Japanese but it may give an idea.
[link](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/tohae/20100626/1277538040)